# Convert Erlang integer to positional notation binary

Tags: binary, integer, erlang

I can convert an integer to a binary easily in Erlang:

```
integer_to_binary(11, 10).
```

The bits in the returned binary are in this case contains these bits:

```
0011000100110001
```

I'd like write a function to generate a binary containing the binary-notation of the number passed in. That is, the number eleven would look like this in bits:

```
1011
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Erlang?

Comment: You mean this `binary:encode_unsigned/1`? `binary:encode_unsigned(11) == <<0:4, 1:1, 0:1, 1:1, 1:1>>.`? If not, then what exact value do you expect for `11`?

Comment: Wow. I completely missed that when reading through the docs. That's exactly what I was looking for! If you throw together a quick answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an arbitrary sized unsigned integer to a binary consisting of the bytes in the integer, you can use `binary:encode_unsigned/1` or `binary:encode_unsigned/2`.

```
1> binary:encode_unsigned(11).
<<"\v">>
2> binary:encode_unsigned(11) == <<0:4, 1:1, 0:1, 1:1, 1:1>>.
true
```

`binary:encode_unsigned/1` will store the bytes in big endian representation. To store the bytes in little endian, you can use `binary:encode_unsigned/2`:

```
1> binary:encode_unsigned(123456789, little).
<<21,205,91,7>>
2> binary:encode_unsigned(123456789, big).
<<7,91,205,21>>
```